# Persist context between test class files in MsTest

Tags: mstest, auth0

I have a scenario where I generate an access token. I need to use the same access token in all the tests across all test cases as well as all tests in other files too. I need this because I do not want to generate an access token each time. There is a way to save access token in persistence storage and read from there. But I am searching for a way in which we can generate the token once and share across all tests without regenerating that. Is there a way to do that in MsTest?

Answer (score 2):

It's Konrad here, I'm an Auth0 Community Engineer.

We do not have any specific tips for testing with MsTest but we've got some overall docs on that:

1) https://auth0.com/docs/support/testing

2) https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/get-access-tokens-for-test

When it comes to getting access tokens for testing, unfortunately to what you said and what is stated in our docs, it's not recommended to have a long expiration time token and even refreshing it.

We do advise to use short expiration times and issue a new one every time you need it.

Comment: The problem is, if I get a new token every time, it exceeds the limit of M2M logins allowed for a month and there are extra charges for that. Instead what I want is to be able to log in once, refresh the token each time instead of having to log in every time. But for that I need to share the refresh token between tests.

Comment: Gotchya! Then unfortunately it's not doable with the way our engineering team prepared the testing mode with our stack. Terribly sorry for that!